# Batch file only showing the first color mentioned

Tags: batch-file, colors, goto

I have made this script that is supposed to change the color of text depending on how much space your C drive has. But it only changes to the color mentioned. For example if I put
**:Red**
and then
**:Blue**,
it would only go to red and ignore the blue section.
This is the code for my script. Please let me know how to fix it if you can.

```
@echo off
title Disk Space Calculator


:Welcome
echo Welcome to the Disk Space Calculator (DSC)! This program will change colour depending on disk space. For example...
echo 2TB - 1TB Cyan
echo 1TB - 750GB Blue
echo 750GB - 500GB Green
echo 500GB - 250GB  Yellow
echo 250GB - 100GB Orange
echo 100GB or less Red
echo This program is recommended for disk with 2TB or less.
echo Please not that available space will be measured in bytes.
pause
goto Calculation

:Calculation
cls
FOR /F "tokens=3 USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`dir /-c /w C:`) DO set "size=%%F"
echo Your disk has %size% bytes of space
if %size%=="2199023255552" goto Cyan
if %size%=="1099511627776" goto Blue
if %size%=="805306368000" goto Green
if %size%=="536870912000" goto Yellow
if %size%=="268435456000" goto Orange
if %size%=="107374182400" goto Red

:Cyan
color b
pause
exit

:Blue
color 1
pause
exit

:Green
color a
pause
exit

:Yellow
color e 
pause
exit

:Orange
color 6
pause 
exit

:Red
color 4
pause
exit
```

Comment: I think you should consider doing the lottery if you are expecting the hard disk space to exactly match a very specific number of bytes. There's a very good chance, the size would be reported, and the console color would turn to cyan before closing, even once if you fix your main issue. Your main issue is that an unquoted variable value is never going to match a quoted series of digits. (`If "%var%" == "string"`)

Comment: Oh OK thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

### Color (Understanding Control Flow)

As Compo mentioned, all your size tests against the constants do not match and therefore the control flow does not branch to any of your defined "color jump points". The control flow just continues to execute the next statements which are in the following `:Cyan` section in your given example. Then that color is applied and the execution stops at the `exit` statement of the Cyan section.
Usually you put a "default branch" after the rows of many comparisons to avoid the control flow pass by into unwanted parts of your script.

Example Snippet:

```
[...]
if "%size%" == "536870912000" goto Yellow
if "%size%" == "268435456000" goto Orange
if "%size%" == "107374182400" goto Red
goto nomatch

:nomatch
echo Your drive size '%size%' did not match any of the known constants.
pause
exit

:Cyan
[...]
```

In the "nomatch" section you often times print some help about the usage of your script or some copyright and version info, as you like.

### Drive Sizes (Computing with large numbers)

Your project is not the easiest to be realized with a batch script.
Unfortunately batch scripts are restricted to integer artithmetics. This means, the largest number you can  process in integer comparisons is 2^32 (One Integer has 32 Bit) which is short over 4 billion (exactly 4,294,967,296).
Your attempt on comparing drive sizes of Gigabyte to Terabyte scale in numbers representing single Bytes will always result in an error message, if the number of bytes exceed this 4 billion limit which is only about 4 GB - what a bummer! `:(`
The only way to check on large drive sizes inside a batch file is to get the values in Mega- or Gigabytes scale. Even a 2TB drive would "just" have about 2000 GB which is well within the range of 4 billion. Doing 2TB in Megabytes would be 2,000,000 MB which would stay under the limit as well and gives a little more accurate numbers, but not down to the last byte.

Now, to "recompute" the long numbers into shorter Gigabyte values you need to resort to String manipulation. The idea is that 2TB in Bytes (=2199023255552) can be shortened by the last 9 digits and the result is roughly in GB, in this case the result would be 2199 GB.

To cut the numbers last digits refer to this principle: `%variablename:~X,Y%` which is documented in the help for `set` (type `set /?` inside a cmd.exe window to see the documentation).
The mentioned syntax allows cutting strings from a starting position X with a length of Y characters (or digits for that matter). Conveniently, you also can specify negative lengths, which means "to the last but Y characters". You would therefore use somehting like `set size_gb=%size:~0,-9%` to cut your size String (the first digit has the index position 0).
If you have numbers smaller than 1 Gigabyte the result would be an empty String (`""`) since you essentially cut away every digit.

With this knowledge you can build up something like this

```
if not "%size:~0,-9%" == "" (
  set size_gb=%size:~0,-9%
  echo Size in GB is: %size_gb%
)
```

‬
I hope you can get your script to work from there on your own. I wish you best of luck and much fun on learning and experiencing new things with your project :)

By the way: Also check out `if /?` on the command line to read the documentation about comparisons. You might want to compare sizes with "greater than" logic (GTR, >=) instead of just "equal to" (EQU, ==).